# How to recover Personal Access Token In Github?

Tags: github

Is there any option to recover Personal Access Token in Github?

Because my app is using the PAT in composer and I don't want to replace it.

Comment: https://cln.sh/XfgQoO _"Make sure to copy your new personal access token now. You won't be able to see it again!"_ The warning seems pretty clear. But creating a new PAT is painless.

Comment: @yivi by mistakenly I have deleted my old PTA. So, is there any option to recover it?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to replace it ([OAuth Authorizations](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/rest/reference/oauth-authorizations#create-a-new-authorization)), since a token cannot be accessed after the generation step.

In a bash shell:

```bash
curl https://api.github.com/authorizations \
  -X POST \
  --user "YourGitHubUsername" \
  --data '{"scopes":["gist","repo],"note":"new token"}'
```

(replace "new token" by something more meaningful)

Comment: Getting response as following

{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}

Comment: @RahulTank OK. What shell are you using, on which OS?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu terminal to execute curl request.

Comment: @RahulTank Can you try with an addition parameter POST? I have edited the answer.

Comment: Still getting same result.

Comment: @RahulTank I suspect you would need to add a `-u username:$token` to authenticate you to GitHub, allowing you to add a new token. Which  means, to create a new token, you still need an existing valid one!